# Android: Notification action click non-uniform behavior

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

I have issue in notification i am using firebase for notification.

Scenario is - when notification received it has two action button accordingly notification will redirect but i didn't perform any operation and i received second notification in that case intent which i set for second notification will loss. It happens only when both notification redirect to the same activity but performs different operation.

here is my code for create notification.

```
private void createNotification(Map<String, Object> dataMap) {

        final String type = dataMap.get("type") + "";
        if (CommonUtil.isEmpty(type)) {
            return;
        }

        final FirebaseService.NotificationType notificationType = FirebaseService.NotificationType.valueOf(type);
        final String alert = dataMap.get("alert") + "";
        String title = dataMap.get("title") + "";

        String notificationMessage = alert;


        notificationSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        unreadNotifications.add(0, notificationMessage);
        android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
        if (unreadNotifications.size() > 1) {
            inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("MyApp");
            for (String unreadNotification : unreadNotifications) {
                inboxStyle.addLine(unreadNotification);
            }
            inboxStyle.setSummaryText(unreadNotifications.size() + " new notifications.");
        }

        Intent intent;
        intent = new Intent(app, LandingActivity.class);
        if (dataMap.containsKey("code")) {
            intent.putExtra(IntentExtras.CODE_FROM_NOTIFICATION, dataMap.get("code") + "");
        }

        intent.setAction(System.currentTimeMillis() + "");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = TaskStackBuilder.create(app)
                .addNextIntent(intent)
                .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        int icon_one = 0, icon_two = 0;
        String actionTextOne = null, actionTextTwo = null;
        PendingIntent actionOne = null, actionTwo = null;
        Intent intentActionOne = null, intentActionTwo = null;

        if (notificationType.equals(NotificationType.REQUEST_RECEIVED)) {
            icon_one = R.drawable.cancel;
            icon_two = R.drawable.notification_track;

            actionTextOne = "Edit";
            actionTextTwo = "Cancel";

            intentActionOne = new Intent(app, LandingActivity.class);
            intentActionOne.putExtra(IntentExtras.CODE_FROM_NOTIFICATION, dataMap.get("code") + "");
            intentActionOne.putExtra(IntentExtras.EDIT, true);

            intentActionTwo = new Intent(app, LandingActivity.class);
            intentActionTwo.putExtra(IntentExtras.CODE_FROM_NOTIFICATION, dataMap.get("code") + "");
            intentActionTwo.putExtra(IntentExtras.CANCEL, true);

        } else if (notificationType.equals(NotificationType.REQUEST_CANCELED)) {
            icon_one = R.drawable.reschedule;
            icon_two = R.drawable.help;

            actionTextOne = "Reschedule";
            actionTextTwo = "Help?";

            intentActionOne = new Intent(app, LandingActivity.class);
            intentActionOne.putExtra(IntentExtras.RESCHEDULE, true);

            intentActionTwo = new Intent(app, LandingActivity.class);
            intentActionTwo.putExtra(IntentExtras.HELP, true);
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(app)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.status_bar_icon)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(app.getResources(), R.drawable.notifications))
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(alert)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(notificationSound)
                .setLights(Color.CYAN, 3000, 3000)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);

        if (notificationType.equals(NotificationType.REQUEST_RECEIVED) || notificationType.equals(NotificationType.REQUEST_CANCELED)) {
            actionOne = TaskStackBuilder.create(app)
                    .addNextIntent(intentActionOne)
                    .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            actionTwo = TaskStackBuilder.create(app)
                    .addNextIntent(intentActionTwo)
                    .getPendingIntent(1, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            builder.addAction(icon_one, actionTextOne, actionOne)
                    .addAction(icon_two, actionTextTwo, actionTwo);
        }

        Notification notification = builder.build();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            int smallIconViewId = getResources().getIdentifier("right_icon", "id", android.R.class.getPackage().getName());

            if (smallIconViewId != 0) {
                if (notification.contentIntent != null)
                    notification.contentView.setViewVisibility(smallIconViewId, View.INVISIBLE);

                if (notification.headsUpContentView != null)
                    notification.headsUpContentView.setViewVisibility(smallIconViewId, View.INVISIBLE);

                if (notification.bigContentView != null)
                    notification.bigContentView.setViewVisibility(smallIconViewId, View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) app.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify("MyApp", Long.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()).intValue(), notification);
    }
```

when i get notification for REQUEST_RECEIVED and didn't  perform any click operation and then if next notification received for REQUEST_CANCELED in that case second notification action click performs clicks operation of first notification while action sets for second notification doesn't  work.

waiting for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if it will work, but I would put something like this:

```
intentActionOne.setAction("ACTION_ONE");
intentActionTwo.setAction("ACTION_TWO");
```

and/or

```
actionOne = TaskStackBuilder.create(app)
                    .addNextIntent(intentActionOne)
                    .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
actionTwo = TaskStackBuilder.create(app)
                    .addNextIntent(intentActionTwo)
                    .getPendingIntent(1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: @Raphul i already tried that sol. but FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT will remove previous pending intent and update it with so it will not working.

Comment: have you tried this combination with setAction() method on those intents?

Comment: ok, last thought because I've had an app with many notifications at the same time and had similar issue. For NotificationType.REQUEST_RECEIVED setAction "ACTION_ONE" and "ACTION_TWO", and for NotificationType.REQUEST_CANCELED put "ACTION_THREE" and "ACTION_FOUR"